# MySQL | Order By computed select value

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by

In mysql is it possible to orderby using a computed select value? For example I have something similar to the following:

```
SELECT members.*, ROUND(formula for finding distance) AS distance
FROM members
ORDER BY distance ASC
```

But when executing the query I am met with a message stating `Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'distance' in 'order clause'`

Comment: MySQL or MS Sql Server? That should work in MySQL unless the spelling of "distance" in the aliasing and the ORDER BY do not match.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can't use aliases the `order by` clause. You could, however, just use the same expression (BTW, note that `order by` are two words, not one):

```
SELECT   members.*, ROUND(formula for finding distance) AS distance
FROM     members
ORDER BY ROUND(same formula for finding distance) ASC
```

Comment: MySQL allows use of SELECT fields' aliases pretty much everywhere but the WHERE clause (and other SELECT fields' expressions).

Answer (score 1):

In MySQL, of course an alias can be used in the `ORDER BY`.  This is pretty typical for distance calculations:

```
SELECT members.*, ROUND(formula for finding distance) AS distance
FROM members
ORDER BY distance ASC;
```

Most databases allow this construct.

Here is a [Rextester](http://rextester.com/VJA1954) demonstrating it working.

Answer (score 0):

try something like this:

```
SELECT members.*, ROUND(formula for finding distance) AS distance
FROM members
ORDER BY ROUND(formula for finding distance) ASC
```